# block client from accessing apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I have been experincing massive requests from certain ips to my apache http server.
Although I Deny from xxxx so that xxx gets a 403 forbidden response.  It still consumes my server's resource.  Is there a way to further block the client from these ips?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows, you can setup custom inbound rules in windows firewall using the GUI (start, run, wf.msc)

If you are using Linux, use IPTABLES:

Drop traffic from 192.x.x.x on port 80 only:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.x.x.x -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

Drop all traffic from 25.55.55.55 on any port:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 25.55.55.55 -j DROP
```

If you post what distribution you are using (providing its linux ofcourse) we can point you to some basic tutorials for setting up IPTABLES.

EDIT 1: Heres a guide for Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo